# <cmd> key code?

Tags: key-bindings

An [article](https://skippi.medium.com/ideas-for-non-leader-vim-mappings-fd32a2769c87) on key-mapping uses `<Cmd>` where I would expect `:`

```
nnoremap [q <Cmd>cprev<CR>
nnoremap ]q <Cmd>cnext<CR>
nnoremap [t <Cmd>tprev<CR>
nnoremap ]t <Cmd>tnext<CR>
```

The author apparently distinguishes between the two:

```
nnoremap g<CR> <Cmd>Git<CR>
nnoremap g<Space> :Git<Space>
nnoremap g. <Cmd>Gvdiffsplit<CR>
nnoremap g/ :sil!gr<Space>
nnoremap g! <Cmd>FzfProcKill<CR>
xnoremap g& <Esc><Cmd>'<,'>&&<CR> " note visual mapping
nnoremap z/ <Cmd>BLines<CR>
```

`<Cmd>` is not in `:h keycodes`. How is this different from `:`, if at all? Is it platform-specific? I'm on Windows and I want to implement the four "Unimpaired" mappings above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained under `:h <Cmd>` (if you can't find it then your Vim is out-of-date). To put it briefly, it doesn't switch modes. Consider output from the following:

```
vnoremap q :<C-U>echo mode()<CR>
vnoremap Q <Cmd>echo mode()<CR>
```

Apparently, some of the mappings *need* to switch the mode to cmdline. So `<Cmd>` cannot be used there. For others, it's a matter of personal preference. Except for `g&`, where `<Cmd>` looks quite ugly, IMO.

Comment: I would go as far to say the `g&` map is _wrong_, defeating the purpose of `<Cmd>` in the first place.  Using `:` there is what is actually wanted.

Comment: @Mass Well, at the end of the day it seems to do what it is meant for. So maybe we can't call it wrong. But, yes, it actually does switch the mode, so it is a very strange way "to emulate" a single colon by a longer series of other commands without clear reason.

Comment: Apparently my Vim is out-of-date. Can you explain the advantage of mapping `<Cmd>cprev<CR>` over `:cprev<CR>` in the normal mode? Don't you go back to the normal mode either way after execution?

Comment: @bongbang It never enters cmdline-mode, so there'll be no `CmdlineEnter/CmdlineLeave` events; no range automatically added; never echoing keys as if typed; no builtin `c_XXX` keys working; no user mappings apply etc. Not too much, actually. So in practice you can think that in Normal mode `<Cmd>` is the same as `nnoremap <silent> :<C-U>`.

Comment: What's the reason for `<C-U>` after `:`? Isn't  `<C-U>`  just for deleting everything after `:`, which in this case is nothing?

Comment: @bongbang Not always. See `:h N:`

Answer (score 3):

The reason `<Cmd>` is not used in

```
nnoremap g<Space> :Git<Space>
```

is because `<Cmd>` shortcut mappings must end with `<cr>`, in other words they must be a complete mapping.  The author of the above map wants a partial mapping, putting `Git`  into your cmdline.